# Botium core -Frequent test failure with message " AllInstitutions_3/Line 7: error sending to bot Error"

Tags: chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

On running `"npm run mocha"` my convo files are picked up but in 3/3 tries
atleast 1 of 3 convo file is failing randomly. There are no issues in the convo files. On rerun they seem to pass

```
• I have 4 convo files
• I do "npm run mocha"
• Result : 3 passing 1 failing
```

[image: Console result of my test run]

> `AllInstitutions_3: Error: AllInstitutions_3/Line 7: error sending to bot Error: Skill simulation for simulation id 642cfacf-7dcd-4791-a949-291121a4e9b9 failed with message: An unexpected error occurred. at pollSimulationResult (N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot-api\node_modules\botium- connector-alexa-smapi\dist\botium-connector-alexa-smapi-cjs.js:532:28) at apiWrapper.callGetSimulation.data (N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot- api\node_modules\botium-connector-alexa-smapi\dist\botium-connector- alexa-smapi-cjs.js:476:23) at Request.request [as _callback] (N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot- api\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\api\request-wrapper.js:72:17) at Request.self.callback (N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot- api\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22) at Request.emit (events.js:189:13) at Request.<anonymous> (N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot-api\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10) at Request.emit (events.js:189:13) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot-api\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12) at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) TranscriptError: Error: AllInstitutions_3/Line 7: error sending to bot Error: Skill simulation for simulation id 642cfacf-7dcd-4791-a949-291121a4e9b9 failed with message: An unexpected er ror occurred. at pollSimulationResult (node_modules\botium-connector-alexa-smapi\dist\botium-connector-alexa-smapi-cjs.js:532:28) at apiWrapper.callGetSimulation.data (node_modules\botium-connector-alexa-smapi\dist\botium-connector-alexa-smapi-cjs.js:476:23) at Request.request [as _callback] (node_modules\ask-cli\lib\api\request-wrapper.js:72:17) at Request.self.callback (node_modules\request\request.js:185:22) at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) at async.waterfall (node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\Convo.js:223:25) at wrapper (node_modules\async\dist\async.js:272:20) at next (node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4584:24) at N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot-api\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:325:20 at runConversation (node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\Convo.js:201:15) at async.mapSeries (node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\Convo.js:396:9) at err (node_modules\async\dist\async.js:252:13) at wrapper (node_modules\async\dist\async.js:272:20) at iterateeCallback (node_modules\async\dist\async.js:417:21) at N:\Chatbots_Repo\bot-api\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:325:20 at
>   _iteratee (node_modules\async\dist\async.js:249:17) at convoStepDone (node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\Convo.js:267:11) at scriptingEvents.setUserInput.then.then.then.then.catch (node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\Convo.js:307:15) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! bot-api@1.0.0 mocha: mocha test\Botium_poc\Spec npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the bot-api@1.0.0 mocha script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!`

Comment: Please enable verbose mode and attach logfile.

Comment: Okay I'll come back with that

Comment: It seems to be working fine now